# Slicing array into 2 parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of N elements.

```
x = [ 1  , 2, ....... , N]
```

How can i split it into 8:2 arrays?

The first array should have 80% elements and the second rest.

Comment: Well break down the problem: How do you calculate the cutoff between the end of the first ~80% and the start of the last ~20%, and then knowing that cuttoff, how do you slice the array?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7311767

Comment: Use `split`: `np.split(x, (8*len(x)//10,))`

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate the ratio, you need to first find the length of the list `x`:

```
len(x)
```

To find 80% of the list, multiply the length by 80%:

```
len(x)*.8
```

This will return a `float`. You need to convert it into an `int` for list slicing:

```
int(len(x)*.8)
```

Next you need to slice the list. [Here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) is a good resource on the basics of list slicing. It will look something like this:

```
x[:int(len(x)*.8)]
```

See if you can figure out how to make the second list for the remaining 20%.

Answer (score 2):

first enter any list
`x=[1,2,3....n]`
then do this function
`y=(Len(x) * 4) // 5`
then split it to 2 lists
`a=x[0:y]`
`b=x[-(Len(x)-y):]`